# Chart or Graph Creation in the opened excel with the macros of same sheet

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript how can I create a graph in opened Excel sheet itself? Code I have written in macro is:

```
Set objWriteExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objWriteExcel.Visible = False
Set objWriteWorkbook = objWriteExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\Surendra\VBCode\Graph\newSheet.xls")
Set objWriteSheet = objWriteWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set objWriteSheet2 = objWriteWorkbook.Worksheets(2)   
Set oMychart = objWriteSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50, 50, 1000, 500).Chart   
oMychart.ChartType = 73
oMychart.SetSourceData objWriteSheet2.Range("A2:B2001")   
oMychart.ChartTitle.Text = "Acclaration VS Time"
objWriteWorkbook.SaveAs ("E:\Surendra\VBCode\Graph\newSheet.xls"), -4143
objWriteExcel.Quit
```

here in `newsheet.xls` when I created on some cell it should take the data from sheet2 of the same workbook and create a graph. But if my sheet already opend and if I use `workbooks.open` command I am not getting the chart. Without the object I think script is not going to work.

If I run this macro as VBScript file then it is working fine, but if a added the same code to a sheet as macro and run then it is not working.

Can someone help me how to plot graph in the same open sheet.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual question is. Are you asking how the VBScript code could be converted to VBA?

Comment: Actual problem is when i click on one cell of sheet1 then macro should plot the graph in the sheet1 by taking the values from sheet2 of same excel sheet. as vbscript works with objects not by activesheet method. i tried to create the object for opened sheet and execute it. but i am not able to get the graph.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to pick an existing chart in your worksheet, so you can modify it? That can be achieved like this: `Set oMychart = objWriteSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart`.

Comment: I want to execute a macro by clicking on a cell in sheet1 of excel sheet.      Procedure for reproducing:
1. open oneExcel sheet 
2. write some data in sheet2 of same excelsheet
3. assign macro for cell click
4. once if we click on the  cell the macro will execute

VBScript code for follwing steps:

5. macro functionality should be it has to take the data from shaeet2 of sameexcel and create graph in sheet1 of same excel

i want the VBScript code which plots the graph in sheet1 of excel by taking the data from shet2 of same excel. 

Thanks for your patience. am i make sence to you?

Comment: It has nothing to do with VBScript. You should change the tag as it is misleading other users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to react on a single click event. However, you could react to `SelectionChange` events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  'do stuff
End Sub
```

Note that this macro won't fire when you click on the currently selected cell, only when you select a different cell than before.

Also, the macro must be bound to a worksheet. Open the macro editor and double-click "Sheet1" in the project explorer window. Enter the code in the new code window. See [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-event-ms-excel-cell-selected-40335.html) for a more detailed description.

Record the graph creation as a macro and paste it into the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` procedure.

Comment: I got the way to assign the macro for cell selection.
but the only problem is when i am trying to source the data i got object required error.
when we record a macro in excel the code generated from excel is VBA code. 
but i need the VBScript code for the same.
As VBScript can not understand the Activechart and ActiveSheet.
how can i convert below VBA code to VBScript code.
Sub Macro1() 
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B20")
End Sub

Comment: @surendra That doesn't make any sense. The code triggered by the event is a macro. Why would you need VBScript code when you're running a macro anyway?